# While loop limit times

Tags: python

How to retry this function when an error occurs, with a maximum of three retries?

```
def crawl(url):
        while True:           
            try:                    
                data = os.popen('wget  -qO- -T10 --tries=1 --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11 "  %s'% url).read()        
                return data
            except Exception, e:
                print e 
                pass

crawl("http://aaa.com")
```

How to retry 3 times inside this `while` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a counter to the loop condition.

```
c = 0
while c < 3:
  try:
    ..
  except ...
    c = c + 1
```

Comment: Nice solution. Minor feedback point: `expect` should be `except` :)

Comment: of course :) fixed